# Where was this stock photo taken?

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this, photography

It's one of the background choices for Linux Mint. I tried doing a reverse Google image search and found [this website](https://www.stockio.com/free-photo/valley-shontz-photography), but it doesn't say where it was taken.

[image]

Comment: This looks shopped. I can tell from some of the pixels and from seeing quite a few shops in my time. (My suspicion: they've enriched the colours)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm most photos are 'shopped' that way, even those that aren't

Comment: The photographer had left an answer here, but now it's been deleted? I wonder what happened, I thought his response was a really neat addition to this thread!

Comment: You're not the only person to wonder that.  See [this meta question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4554/what-happened-to-the-answer-to-this-stock-photo-question) for the answer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can eventually follow the link you sent out to the photographer's Flickr website:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/shontzphotography/15169016487/in/album-72157645951788784/

In the discussion area, it looks to be from an area in *Te Mata Peak in Havelock North, New Zealand*.

Comment: Never fails: is it too gorgeous to possibly be a real place on Earth? Then it's in Middle-Earth, ahem, sorry, New Zealand. :)

Comment: It is a nice area, actually nicer once you take away all the garish photoshopping that made me as a kiwi, *not* recognise it.

Answer (score 22):

Here's a similar view from Google Earth (you can see the exact coordinates in the lower right corner). It looks like the photographer used a wide angle lens and the sunrise really brings out the contours of the valley floor.

[image]

Comment: Looks almost as good as the original!

Comment: Just missing the saturation ...

Comment: Good job! Google Maps link: https://goo.gl/maps/ZddEmYmSrA12